# App to download rss enclosures (just like a podcatcher)

Tags: applications, sync, downloading, rss

Is there an Android app that is able to download rss enclosures? I want to setup [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) on a server to download articles from some newspaper-sites and converts them to .epub.

Then I want to have an RSS-feed of those epub-files.

Finally I want my Sony PRS-T1 to download all (new) epub-files that are linked in this rss feed.

How would you do that?